# importar solo un componente de boostrap

Tags: bootstrap

necesito importar solo de boostrap las nav-tabs porque no puedo usar boostrap completo, porque me rompe en el codigo. Solo quiero usar especificamente eso. Se puede?? Se que se pueden importar la libraria del carrousel, por ejemplo, pero nunca vi si solo podia sacar el css de ese componente.

Comment: Agrega las tecnologias que estas usando.

Comment: Lo vi en la v3 de bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/ no sé si en la última versión actual 5.3 exista algo equivalente. No indicaste la versión que usas.

Comment: Para ocupar los componentes de bootstrap tienes que añadirlo en tu proyecto.